# compare foreach value to $_POST in php

Tags: php, json, post

I'm populating select box with options from json file and trying to set value from `$_POST` as selected. I get all the values printed as options but none selected.
Seems like something goes wrong when comparing `$marke` to `$post` so nothing get selected.

```
<select name="marke" id="marke"class="form-control">
    <?php
    $url = 'includes/lists/models.json';
    $jsonData = file_get_contents($url); 
    $jsonDataObject = json_decode($jsonData, true);
    $post = $_POST['marke'];
    $i = 0;             
    echo '<option>--</option>';
    foreach ($jsonDataObject['markes'] as $marke) {
        if ($marke==$post) {
            echo '<option selected value="'.$marke['title'].'" id="'.$i.'">'.$marke['title'].'</option>';
        }else{
            echo '<option value="'.$marke['title'].'" id="'.$i.'">'.$marke['title'].'</option>';
        }
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

P.S `$_POST['marke']` is set correcly.

Comment: `echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.$marke['title'].'" id="'.$i.'">'.$marke['title'].'</option>';`

Comment: Tried this. No changes.

Comment: view the source of the generated HTML and you will be able to see what is wrong.

Comment: Everything is ok in there. Seems like something goes wrong when comparing $marke to $post so nothing get selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it `$marke` is an array, and most likely `$_POST['marke']` is a string or int.

```
 if ($marke['title']==$post) {
```

instead of

```
 // You'd be comparing a $marke array with $_POST['marke'] string
 if ($marke==$post) {
```

Comment: This helped. Thank you!